# Making iteration recursive using PERL

Tags: perl, recursion

Bon,

I have this code which is a simple loop, which works… to call it you need to send it a reference to an array of numbers.

```
@blah = (0b0010,0b010,0b0111);
$ans = &logical_loop(\@blah);

sub logical_loop()
{
    my $codes = $_[0];
    my $ans = 0;
    foreach (@$codes) {
        printf "%b\n",$_;
    $ans = ($ans | $_)
    }
    return($ans);
}
```

I wanted to make it recursive, so I wrote this code which doesn't work…. please can somebody tell me what I have missed? something to do with variables scopes perhaps?

```
sub recursive_loop 
{
    my $codes = $_[0];
    my $el = shift @$codes;
    if (@$codes == ()) {
        return ($el | $answer);
    } else {
        $answer = (&recursive_loop(\@$codes) | $el);
    }
}
```

Comment: For recursive functions you have to invoke the function `recursive_loop` (add underline in its name) into itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub recursive_loop {
  return 0 unless @_;
  my $head = shift;
  return $head | recursive_loop(@_);
}

@blah = (0b0010,0b010,0b0111);
recursive_loop(@blah);
```

More efficient tail recursive:

```
sub or_it_up {
  unshift @_, 0;
  goto &recursive_loop;
}

sub recursive_loop {
  my $ans = shift;
  return $ans unless @_;
  unshift @_, $ans | shift;
  goto &recursive_loop;
}

@blah = (0b0010,0b010,0b0111);
or_it_up(@blah);
```

You can use calling recursive_loop as function but in this way it will not make stack frame.

You can also write it simply without `or_it_up` which serves just educational purpose. Calling `recursive_loop` directly will make result caused by nature of binary or.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with your subroutine.

- its name contains a spacing mark
- it doesn't call itself therefore no recursion is possible

Comment: Thanks; I edited the code after I posted it; corrected those bits